# Thread Barrier synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, barrier

I want to implement a Barrier synchronization technique on threads

So far I've come up with some code, but I have some questions..

```
    struct _ThreadBarrier {

    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int needed;
    int waiting;
    int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *restrict cond, pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex); 
    pthread_mutex_t mut;
}


some other code for initilization etc ..




void enterBarrier(ThreadBarrier *barrier) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier->mut);


    waiting ++;
    if (waiting == needed){

            barrier->cond = 1;
            barrier->waiting = 0;
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&barrier->cond);


   }else{
           barrier->cond = 0;
           pthread_cond_wait&barrier->cond,&barrier->mut); 
   }



   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mult);

   }
```

And so I have some questons on the mutex. I am sure that on entering the func. enterBarrier I must lock the mutex, so that no other thread gets it and alters and the same time "waiting"! But I unlock the mutex and the end of the code and I am not sure if other threads ever will go in enterBarrier, because of the locked mutex.

I am not entirely sure how exactly this mutex works.

Comment: People that ask questions on Stackoverflow are expected to do basic research before hand. Your question is not really about the code you have shown but about mutexes in general. And you should be able to find lots of info about that on the Web. Start by taking the time to read the [pthread man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) which if understood will answer your question.

Comment: [If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)

Comment: Yes, I read the man pages :) But It's not clear to me, that's why I ask the question... So the lock, that I have implemented here is valid and will not work as intended? How it is supposed to be? Thanks for the time

Comment: It's not clear what your intention is. "I am not sure if other threads ever will go in enterBarrier". The answer to that is that once the mutex is unlocked by a thread then one of the other threads that is blocked on the lock (if any) will be unblocked and continue execution. That's pretty much exactly what the man page is saying.

Comment: Does `barrier->cond = 1;` even compile?  And if it does, it surely doesn't make sense or work.  Similarly for `barrier->cond = 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should be. To lock/unlock the condition variable, function are needed. The mutex should be locked in the beginning

```
void enterBarrier(ThreadBarrier *barrier) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier->mut);


barrier->waiting ++;

if (barrier->waiting == barrier->needed){

    barrier->waiting = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&barrier->cond);

}else{
    pthread_cond_wait(&barrier->cond,&barrier->mut); 

}

pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mut);
```

}